# Windows Workflow Foundation 4 Create Base Activity

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4

In [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation) 3.x, you used to be able to create a BaseWorkflow class where you could define some properties in that workflow.

And then when you create a workflow you can say it derives from BaseWorkflow class so it inherits all the properties from the base workflow.

Can we achieve the same thing in Windows Workflow Foundation 4 (WF 4)? Like defining InArgument and OutArgument on a BaseActivity then create another Activity that derives from the BaseActivity.

I tried by modify the XAML from let's say <Activity></Activity> to like <BaseActivity></BaseActivity> ... that was the way we did it in WF 3.x.

It doesn't seem to work in WF 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution to this. It's actually quite easy. The class generated by the XAML declaration is marked as `partial` so you can create a class (also marked `partial`) for your activity (workflow) base. Then in XAML, just change the class attribute on your activity to the full namespace of the class you just created.

Base Activity Example:

```
public partial class OurBaseWorkflow : Activity
{
     public InArgument<string> StandardInput { get;set; }
}
```

XAML example:

```
<p:Activity x:Class="MyNamespace.OurBaseWorkflow"
            xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    ...
</p:Activity>
```

With this method, you can define both in and out arguments on the base class and they show up for your derived activities as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a `BaseActivity` and define its InArguments and OutArguments. You can then create a new class, say `Activity1:BaseActivity` and it still has `BaseActivity`'s InArguments and OutArguments

Comment: Can I do this in a XAML only scenario? Without creating a class?

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer. I need a XAML-only solution and replacing the Activity tags in XAML doesnt work as pdiddy indicated.

Comment: Haha...nevermind. Found the answer, as I'm sure pdiddy has by now as well. Answer is posted here so others may stumble upon it.